# Enable submit button after uploading more than 1 file

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I found this partially answered here, what I would need is to enable a submit button, but only after uploading more than 1 file. When I upload just 1, it automatically enables, but what I would need is that the submission doesn´t get enabled until I submit the second file.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
    $('input:file').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()){
                $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
            }
            else {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            }
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ayu5/49/
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/2Ayu5/50/

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($("#file1").val() && $("#file2").val()){
                    $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                }
                else {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                }
            });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" id="file1"/>
    </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
        <input type="file" id="file2"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

See this [Link with Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ayu5/51/)

Use `id` for `file`:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($("#1").val() && $("#2").val()){
                    $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                }
                else {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Yep, Thank u guys, was fast enough!